# Allow Unprivileged User to run a command as a different user

Tags: git, bash, sudo, privileges

I have the following script which works great when I, **with my own sudo privileges**, run it:

```
department_wpsites=("/var/www/asiane/wp-ane" "/var/www/english/wp-english")

for f in ${department_wpsites[*]}
do
    theme_path="$f/wp-content/themes/dept-theme"
    cd $theme_path
    echo ">> Performing 'git pull' at $theme_path"
    sudo -u www-data git pull
done
```

Now I want one of my underlings, who does NOT have sudo privileges, to be able to run it. Notice that the need is for all files modified/created by `git pull` to be owned by www-data, regardless of who runs the script. What can I do to allow a non-sudo user to use this script or something equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sudo can be adjusted to allow the administrator to set up *what* can be run by *who*. It's not like one-size-fits-all "when I add a user into sodoers file the user is automatically an admin" is forced. sodoers allows for fine grained rules that can help you tailor it to meet your needs where a single user is going to be allowed to run a single script **(and nothing else)**.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt

Comment: So I've been trying to use the sudoers file, but I believe the thing that needs to be enabled is the line `sudo -u www-data git pull` (do a git pull as www-data), and my network admin said that you don't put sudo commands within the sudoers file

Comment: I'd say that's missing a missing a lot of the functionality of what sudo can do (it's _not_ just to allow users to become full-blown roots on a .system but to allow them to run specific things they needed _whithout granting them anything else_) Also, I wouldn't just give a user _carte blanche_ to run git anywhere they want to. I'd narrow it down by creating a simple script that would go to the desired location and run ```git whatever``` and nothing else. No parameters read, no nothing. That way the script would be tied. And that's the script I would set up on sudoers.